# How do I do multipled level routes best in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a site where I would like an URL like:

`/Some maincategory name/{id}/Some subcategory name/{id}/Some item name/{id}`

I include the IDs of each level since the name is not unique. This is doable but I have to create a new routing for each level. My Html.ActionLink also looks nasty.

Each level has it's own controller since the levels are completely different. The URLs could be something like this:

```
_/Birds/2/Waders/4/Flamingos/23_  
_/Mammals/5/Dogs/23/Longeared/25/Somedog/76_  
_/Insects/7/Spiders_
```

This is just an example and not what I'm going to use. My applications has nothing to do with animals.

Is there a good way of doing this or should I use the standard routing instead?

Comment: So ... you're saying you will have _/Birds/2/Waders/4/_ *and* _/Birds/48/Waders/7/_ and they will need to be routed to different controllers?  I'm sorry, but my brain hurts just trying to comprehend what you are trying to achieve.  There almost certainly is a way to drop the the ID's, but you haven't given enough, or specific enough, detail to tell, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two solutions for this:

1. Using Global Routing which results in

   http://you.url.com/controller/action/{mid}/{sid}/{tid}

   where mid = main category id
        sid = sub category id
        tid = item id
2. Using the combination of Routing and Query String

   http://you.url.com/controller/action/{tid}?mid={mid}&sid={sid}

I would suggest you use the second method, then you don't have to mass up with the route things. and hope this help!!

Comment: I know how to do this with global routes, but the solution looks ugly and I wanted to know if someone know how to do this in a smarter/cleaner way. Also I have a controller/view for each level and it might be up to 5 levels. I guess what I'd like is a breadcrum in my url...

Comment: I did it the standard MVC way with controller/action/{id} to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an xml file describing your categories, values, urls at each node and then creating a route table by looping through those xml nodes?

That kind of xml can also help you to create bread crumbs on your pages.